# Can an access token be created so the envelopes aren't sent from my individual account but from other users or simply from our company?

Tags: docusignapi

I have created an access token to send documents through an industry software vendor called VieFUND; however, the DocuSign envelopes ALL say they're being sent from myself, as opposed to the individual actually sending the envelope. The package is being initiated in the other software (VieFUND). Have I set something up wrong? I don't want the envelope saying it came from me when sent to clients that are not mine.

I'm not a developer nor do I have access to one.  I'm hopeful this is not an uncommon initial issue and I've simply made a "mistake" with the Integration Key.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many integrations act as an intermediary service or backend service, rather than acting on behalf of the individual users of the main application.  This is likely the case for VieFUND.

What you want to do is create a "service user" that represents the business unit.

1. create an email address for the user, such as "esign_svc@acme.com" or even "no-reply@acme.com".
2. Have your DocuSign Account Administrator create a new user using this email address and a "business" name, such as "eSign Service" or "Account Openings".
3. Activate the user (set a password).  Note: exclude from SSO if necessary.
4. Configure the VieFUND integration to use this service user instead of you.  Now, all the envelopes will come from the business.

Comment: Thank you WTP!  This set me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's called impersonation. It is available via the JWT OAuth grant flow.

However, you need the author of the integration (VieFUND) to handle this issue.

It sounds like VieFUND wants the DocuSign envelope to be sent 'from' the person who has logged in. If so, then you need your colleagues to use (login to) VieFUND if you want the envelopes to come from them.

Comment: Thank you Larry.  As it turns out, even when they log in to VieFUND themselves, the envelopes that are sent still come from me.  Any further thoughts on that?

Comment: You'll need to discuss with the author of the integration, VieFUND